# how to fix "Undefined variable: subtask" in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, laravel-blade

need edit My subtask table records, SubtaskController

```
public function edit($projectId,$taskId,$subtaskId)
    {
        $subtask = Subtask::where('project_id', $projectId)
                      ->where('task_id', $taskId)
                      ->where('id', $subtaskId)
                      ->first();
        return view('subtasks.edit')->withTask($subtask)->with('projectId', $projectId)->with('id',$subtaskId);
        //
```

blade file link to edit button is this,
tasks/index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($task->subtasks as $subtask)
    <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
    <div class="pull-right icons-align">

            <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/subtasks/{{$subtask->id}}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
          <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
        {{ $subtask->subtask_name }}
        </div>

    @endforeach
    }
```

and route is this

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/subtasks/{subtasks}/edit', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\SubtasksController@edit',

]);
```

and edit.blade.php
subtasks/edit.blade.php

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ url('projects/' .$projectId .'/tasks/' . $task->id.'/subtasks/'.$subtask->id) }}"> //this is line 9
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{!! $subtask->subtask_name ?: '' !!}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update Subtask</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
        </form>
```

but when I click edit button fron blade file got this error massage,

```
ErrorException in 9b021095a9def87aed61575bb51efc07798e08da.php line 9: Undefined variable: subtask (View: C:\Users\dnk\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\subtasks\edit.blade.php)
```

how can solve this problem?

Comment: use @if for check variable exists or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
->withTask($subtask)
```

Do this:

```
->withSubtask($subtask)
```

And in the `edit` view change this:

```
$task->id
```

To:

```
$subtask->task->id
```

To make the second fix work, you also need to have a properly defined relationship in `Subtask` model:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Comment: please clear it me where should I change this **$subtask->task->id**

Comment: @DNK in the form `action="{{ url('projects/' .$projectId .'/tasks/' . $task->id.'/subtasks/'.$subtask->id) }}">`

Comment: now got this error **Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\dnk\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\subtasks\edit.blade.php)**

Comment: @DNK that's why I've asked you to change `$task` to `$subtask->task` in the view.

Comment: yes I change edit file action now this is **{{ url('projects/' .$projectId .'/tasks/' . $task->id.'/subtasks/'.$subtask->task->id) }}** is it ok?

Comment: @DNK maybe you didn't show other parts of `edit` view where you're also using `$task`. You need to change all those variables to `$subtask->task`